# How to use a FOR loop in SQL without using cursor

Tags: sql, loops, cursor

I am a beginner at SQL, much more familiar with oob languages, so trying to figure out how to use a loop has been a massive headache. If anyone is familiar with a good resource, I'd really appreciate it?

On to the question.

I have a table where column 1 is percent return, and then column 2 has a starting value and is otherwise empty.

First, I want to update the row 2 column 2 to equal row 1 column 2 amount multiplied by row 2 column 1. Then, for the rest of the table, I want to take the amount in the most recently used cell in column 2 (in our example, it would be row 1), and then multiply it by the percent return in row 3 column 1.

so here's the starting table:

```
column 1| column 2    
,,,     |  10    
1.1     |     
1.2     |    
1.05    |
```

and then here's the resulting table

```
column 1| column 2    
,,      |   10    
1.1     |   11    
1.2     |  13.2    
1.05    |  13.86
```

Comment: What are all the commas in your data?

Comment: I was trying to make it look correctly spaced, sorry if that was confusing

Comment: If you indent everything by 4 spaces, then it will appear as code-formatted in your question (the grey highlighted areas), and displayed in a fixed width font. So then you can just use spaces to achieve the correct spacing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: It looks like you're using MySQL in which case a good tutorial source is http://www.mysqltutorial.org/

Answer (score 0):

A “for loop” in SQL is accomplished via a cursor.

But look into the SQL functions LEAD and LAG.

They’ll cover what you’re describing, the ability to know/use values for 2 adjacent rows.

Comment: Reread your og problem. You need a cursor. Maybe you are trying to avoid using one because you don’t have the right role. I suggest adding a field to your table of you can that you will use as a “counter”. Then write the sql needed to read row 1 and 2 and update row 2 col 2 as well as your counter field. Write another sql stmt that will return the freshly updated row 2. Call the sql dB with these statements using language of your choice and use a loop in that language